# Magento 2 Bundle Products Issue

Tags: magento2

when i click on add to cart button on bundle product 2 times to add 2 bundle products its shows 0 price on cart page. This is issue only for even qty numbers. if i click 3 time on add to cart button from bundle product then its show me exact price on cart page.

[image]